# Is it possible to integrate Control-M with MWAA Airflow to trigger and monitor jobs?

Tags: airflow, orchestration, mwaa, control-m

Pretty new to these orchestration tools. Is it possible to integrate Control-M and mwaa airflow to trigger/ track jobs?

Couldn't find much information regarding the same.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, full support for Airflow was added in Control-M v21 (released in October).